# [Environment]::Exit(0) - MEANING OF THIS?

Tags: powershell, exit

What is the meaning of this line in PowerShell?

I have tried searching on google but I do not see any specific explanations.

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit

Comment: Generally, **do _not_ use `[Environment]::Exit()` in your PowerShell code**: it not only sets the desired exit code, but _instantly terminates_ the _entire process_, and can even bypass cleanup code, as [stated in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit).  

Therefore, if, from within a PowerShell session, you call a script that calls `[Environment]::Exit()`, the *entire session* exits.

**Instead, use `exit <n>`**, where `<n>` is the desired exit code - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

Comment: As for how you could have discovered the API documentation yourself: `[Environment]::Exit(0)` implies the use of .NET type (`[...]`) `System.Environment` (PowerShell allows you to omit the `System.` part) and its static (`::`) `.Exit()` method, so you could have googled `System.Environment.Exit` to find the API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically, programs in MS-DOS and under the Windows Command Line (CMD.EXE) signalled errors by setting the system environment variable `ERRORLEVEL` to a non-zero value. PowerShell does not, by default, do this. If one wishes to invoke a PowerShell script, and have it behave like other programs (and batch files) when called from a batch file, the call to `[Environment]::Exit()` allows you to set `ERRORLEVEL` in a way that is compatible with CMD.EXE's expectations. [You can see more about `[Environment]::Exit()` at Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: PowerShell, by default, does do this.  If your program ends, it returns zero.  If an unhandled exception is thrown, you get a return one.  When you use the `exit` keyword, you're specifying that exit code.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - That's not entirely consistent with my experience; _some_ unhandled exceptions do this, but if it's an error that can be handled (e.g., with try/catch/finally), even if it's unhandled, I can't say I've consistently gotten a non-zero ERRORLEVEL.

Comment: More generally, exit codes are how _processes_ signal success vs. failure to one another. Calling from `cmd.exe` is probably becoming less and less important, but
calls to the PowerShell CLI from build/automation/CI servers are more important than ever.
Note that `ERRORLEVEL` is _not_ a true environment variable - it's just how `cmd.exe` surfaces a child process' exit code.
Use of `[Environment]::Exit()` is problematic, because it unconditionally exits the _entire process_, so it shouldn't be used for code that may _also_ be called from a PowerShell session.

Comment: As for how PowerShell sets its own exit code: the rules are somewhat complex, but I've tried to summarize them in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375). /cc @TheIncorrigible1